# Are there problems if I have a verbose datatype?

Tags: c#, oop, list, dictionary

In my application development, I concluded that I need this variable.

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>> PackageDictionaryForProblems
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>> PackageDictionaryForProblemRules
```

But as I need to access to each key of the dictionary, so it's a pain. I supposed that would be a good option create a class to avoid write all the datatype:

```
public class PackageDictionaryForProblems : IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>>
{ }

// the sane for the second dictionary
```

What do you think about this? Is a good practice to create just this class? Or should I need to create several classes for each one? I.E.

```
public class ProblemCollection : IList<Problem>
{ }
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, because you don't implement `IDictionary`. Did you mean something like `class PackageDictionaryForProblems : Dictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>>` (that is, inheriting from `Dictionary`, not `IDictionary`)?

Comment: Yes, you're. I forgot that point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at runtype between the two options of defining multi-level collections like

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>> PackageDictionaryForProblems
```

or defining/using a type like

```
public class PackageDictionaryForProblems : IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels,     IList<Problem>>>
{ }
```

Without any further functionality in `PackageDictionaryForProblems`, it simply serves as an alias for `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels,     IList<Problem>>>`.

You still end up with the same memory allocation, access times, etc.  Adding that custom type only simplifies readability of your code (or not... personally I find it easier to look at the `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>>` definition to understand the data structure.  That's just personal preference).

Answer (score 2):

> Is a good practice to create just this class?

The main advantage of using a custom class, especially in this case, is that it allows you to simplify the access.

Nested dictionary access can often be simplified by adding higher level member functions, since a "single access" often requires checks for the wrapped dictionary which can add new dictionaries, etc.  Wrapping this into a simple API can dramatically simplify the usage of the type.

If, however, you just expose the underlying types directly, there is little advantage to creating this class over just using the built in types.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to avoid nesting generic types more than one deep unless the types are primitives (eg `string` or `int`).  I would probably refactor so that you have a generic class that maps from `Level`s to `T`s:

```
class LevelMapping<T> {
  IDictionary<Level, T> Mapping {get; set;}

  // constructors/methods etc
}
```

Now you can have an `IDictionary` of `string` to `LevelMapping`s.

```
IDictionary<string, LevelMapping<Problem>> PackageDictionaryForProblems;
IDictionary<string, LevelMapping<ProblemRule>> PackageDictionaryForProblemRules;
```

This of course depends on the specifics of what you're mapping here.  It could be that it is a better fit to wrap the entire dictionary with special methods to better reflect your domain (or to not wrap it at all!).

Answer (score 1):

The three reasons why I use the extra class:

1. Readability.
2. Easy addition of extra methods and properties and overrides
3. Easy changing the type (just replace the base type instead of hunting for the type in my code that is instantiating an object.

Comment: 4. (in the case of a `Dictionary<>`) You always need to construct these with the case in-sensitive comparer and sometimes forget. The extra class can call the base constructor with that comparer.

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, see no reason to create class just to alias some existing functionality.